# accessing HttpServletRequest from an aspectj advice (non-spring)

Tags: aspectj, jersey-2.0, servlet-3.0

I am using servlets 3.0, jersey 2, and NOT Spring.

Here's my endpoint:

```
@Path("/foo")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class Foo {

@GET
@Path("/bar")
  public String bar() {
    return "hello world"
  }
}
```

Here's my pointcut:

```
pointcut endPoints(): execution (@javax.ws.rs.GET * *.*(..));
```

How do I get HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, etc. from within my advice without changing bar's signature and without using Spring?

Regards,
Shackman